# Calling derived class' function from base class pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

If a function is overloaded in a derived class but the function signature is unchanged, is there any way to call the derived class' function from a base class pointer? For instance:

Given the following base and derived classes

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(int n): n_(n) {}
    ~Base() {}
    int get_n() {
    return n_;
    }
private:
    const int n_;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(int n): Base(n), n_(n) {}
    ~Derived() {}
    double get_n() {
    return 1.5*n_;
    }
private:
    const int n_;
};
```

Is there any way to get the following to output `1.5` given that two `get_n()` functions differ only in their return types?

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
Base *b = new Derived(1);
std::cout << b->get_n() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Yes, use `virtual`, or member-function-pointers.

Comment: You are changing the return type of `get_n()` so even if you made it a virtual function it will still not work. You should look at templates maybe or change the classes design

Comment: I cannot use `virtual` if the return type has changed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991133/forcing-late-method-resolution-in-case-of-class-inheritance-in-c

Comment: @Deduplicator, The return type is not part of the signature.

Comment: @chris: You got a better duplicate. Will you close?

Comment: @glinka, Do note that as I say in my answer there, changing the design is a vastly superior solution.

Comment: Yes, I suspected this was the case. Thanks for finding the link.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `get_n` *virtual* in base class. Like,

```
virtual int get_n() 
{
    return n_;
}
```